# What determines the rank of a new soldier rewarded from a mission?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I used to be getting major for such soldiers.

Now I am getting sergeant. What determines the new soldiers I am getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you look at the Reward before accepting the mission, you can see a text that says:

```
New Recruit: [Class]
      ([Rank])
```

[image]

It is that `[Rank]` that tells you which rank your new recruit will be. Recruits won as a reward can be of any rank except rookie, while those recruited through the Barracks are without exception rookies<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup>: If you have learned the "**New Guy**" skill at the Officer Training School, then all rookies will automatically be promoted to squaddies.

Comment: Nicely written, but that's not answering the actual question asked -- **how does the game decide what rank to give as an award?**

Comment: Yea. In my first walk through I usually get major. In second, sergeant.

Comment: @Shadur That really seems like a different question. The rank it says before the missions determines what soldiers you *get*. You're asking what determines which soldiers are *available* as possible mission rewards.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find this on the XCOM wiki [(UFOPaedia)](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Classes_%28EU2012%29#Class_Assignment)

> If a soldier is received as a reward through completion of an Abductions or then its class will be determined by the following criteria [1]:
>
> If any classes have 0 or 1 soldiers alive, there is a 50% chance that one of those classes will be picked (equal chance for each).
>           If the class is not picked in step 1, there is a 50% chance of picking the class with the smallest maximum rank. If multiple classes are tied for the smallest maximum rank then randomly pick one of them.
>           If the class is not picked in step 2, then randomly select a class, with each class having equal chance.
>           If by any chance none of the criteria above is used, then the soldier will be a Heavy.
>
> Abductions rewards can receive the following ranks (chosen randomly):
>   - Sergeant
>   - Captain
>   - 2nd highest rank present in Barracks